# HTML and CSS : horizontal navigation menu with list rotation (DIVI Theme)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, uinavigationbar

I need to have a navigation design something like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQpjI.png]

but what I've been making is like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiplD.png]

I can't figure out the CSS solution.

**Edit**: By the way, I'm using divi theme
and here is my modifications in the css

```
/*------------------------------ Navigation ------------------------------*/
#main-header {
  -webkit-box-shadow:none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:none !important;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}

#et-top-navigation ul.nav {
  font-family: Sintony-Bold, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/*** Here is the rotation of the list items vertically ***/
#et-top-navigation ul.nav li {
  text-align: right !important; /* this make the bullets to the right */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

    list-style-position: inside !important;
}
/*** Adding of bullets to li items ***/
#et-top-navigation ul.nav li:hover::before {
  content: '•';
  color: #fff;
}
#et-top-navigation ul.nav li.current_page_item::before {
  content: '•';
  color: #fff;
  /*font-size: 130%;*/
}

#top-menu a {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  -webkit-text-underline-position: under !important;
  -ms-text-underline-position: under !important;
  text-underline-position: under !important;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

I used the `transform: rotate(-90deg);` to rotate the list items and here is what I got so far
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cfw0.png]

you will see the bullets from the second image on top of the list which is also my problem

Comment: Please share your codes.

Comment: You want a vertical navigation, right, maybe running down the left side of the web page?

Comment: @MichaelMcGinnis Uhm..no. It's actually the <li> items that should be vertical please see https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBf1v.png but the navigation is still full width horizontal

Comment: @RajanBenipuri Please see my answer below

Comment: An addendum was made to the question, but posted in the answer box. Please copy that text, and edit it into the question. You may post a self-answer once you have a full, working solution, as long as you make it clear that it is an answer, and that you include an explanation of your approach (code on its own as an answer is less useful).

Comment: Could you post some of your HTML too? Is it `<div id="et-top-navigation"><ul class="nav" id="top-menu"><li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>`? P.S. You should be able to avoid using `!important` so much. And sorry that I'm not used to sideways text in menus.

Comment: I made a fiddle for experimentation, but it doesn't do much yet: http://jsfiddle.net/atkb3311/

Comment: @MichaelMcGinnis Thank you for your suggestion regarding adding `!important`, I will do that.
HTML is like this
`<div id="et-top-navigation">
  <nav id="top-menu-nav">
   <ul id="top-menu">
     <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>`

Comment: By the way, I'm using Divi theme in my website then I created a child theme and added css modification codes.

Comment: I' m not getting the list items to rotate on http://jsfiddle.net/atkb3311/2/, unless I apply the rotation to `#top-menu li` instead of `#et-top-navigation ul.nav li`. Possibly we could help more if you gave us a live URL.

Comment: here is the URL @MichaelMcGinnis [https://alopogi.000webhostapp.com](https://alopogi.000webhostapp.com)
note: currently, I commented `transform: rotate(-90deg)` for my better testing, so you will see the navigation menus as horizontally aligned.

Comment: No one have any idea for this? :(